# Java Cipher Program issue

Tags: java

I posted this program yesterday and I'm just stuck. I can't figure out why I'm getting the errors I am getting, I've read a bunch of stuff, frankly I as struggling to get Java in general. Any help is appreciated...Code and errors to follow...

```
/*
JursekGregChapter12t.java
Greg Jursek

This program will encrypt entered text by a user input 
shift value and then decrypt text in the same manner.
*/

import java.lang.*;

import java.util.*;

public class JursekGregChapter12t
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String encryptText; // text to be encrypted
    String decryptText; // text to be decrypted
    int shiftValue; // the number of spaces that will be shifted via user input


    // User enters plain text for encryption
    System.out.print("Please enter text to encrypt");
    encryptText = stdIn.next();

    // User enters a shift value
    System.out.println("Please enter shift value");
    shiftValue = stdIn.nextInt();

    // System prints the encrypted text
    String encryptedText = encrypt(encryptText , shiftValue); // text that has been encrypted
    System.out.println(encryptedText);

    // User enters text for decryption
    System.out.print("Please enter text to decrypt");
    decryptText = stdIn.next();

    // User enters a shift value
    System.out.println("Please enter shift value");
    shiftValue = stdIn.nextInt();

    // System prints the decrypted text
    String decryptedText = decrypt(decryptText , shiftValue); // text that has been decrypted
    System.out.println(decryptedText);
} // end main


        // Shift and Character Manipulation
        public static String shift(String enteredText, int shiftValue) 
        {

            String convertedText = "";
            for(int i = 0; i< enteredText.length(); i++)
            {
                char lowerCase = enteredText.charAt(i);

                //Convert to upper case letters
                char lowerCase = Character.toUpperCase(lowerCase);
                int charNumber = upperLetter;

                //Shift letters and wrap text
                int rotateLetters = (charNumber + shiftValue) % 26;
                char shiftLetters = (char)rotateShift;

                //Populate new string of characters
                convertedText += shiftLetters;
            }
        return convertedText;
        }

        // Encryption code
        public static String encrypt(String enteredText, int shiftValue)
        {
            String encryptedString = rotate(enteredText , shiftValue);
            return encryptedString;
        }

        // Decryption code
        public static String decrypt(String enteredText, int shiftValue)
        {
            int negativeShiftValue = (-1) * (shiftValue);
            String decryptedString = rotate(enteredText , negativeShiftValue);
            return decryptedString;
        }


} //end class JursekGregChapter12t
```

Errors:

```
/Users/Greg/Documents/Programming/Java/JursekGregChapter12t.java:59: error: variable lowerCase is already defined in method shift(String,int)
                    char lowerCase = Character.toUpperCase(lowerCase);
                         ^
/Users/Greg/Documents/Programming/Java/JursekGregChapter12t.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
                    int charNumber = upperLetter;
                                 ^
  symbol:   variable upperLetter
  location: class JursekGregChapter12t
/Users/Greg/Documents/Programming/Java/JursekGregChapter12t.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
                    char shiftLetters = (char)rotateShift;
                                              ^
  symbol:   variable rotateShift
  location: class JursekGregChapter12t
/Users/Greg/Documents/Programming/Java/JursekGregChapter12t.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
                String encryptedString = rotate(enteredText , shiftValue);
                                         ^
  symbol:   method rotate(String,int)
  location: class JursekGregChapter12t
/Users/Greg/Documents/Programming/Java/JursekGregChapter12t.java:83: error: cannot find symbol
                String decryptedString = rotate(enteredText , negativeShiftValue);
                                         ^
  symbol:   method rotate(String,int)
  location: class JursekGregChapter12t
5 errors
[Finished in 2.7s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Where have you declared `rotateShift`, `upperLetter` etc ?

Comment: Start by fixing the first one. Read the error message. What does it say? *variable lowerCase is already defined in method shift(String,int)*. And indeed, you're declaring the lowerCase variable twice. So fix the code: either you want a different variable, and it should have another name, or you want to reuse the same, and you shouldn't declare it a second time. Only reassign it. You should never come to a point where you have so many errors. Add as few lines as possible to an already compiling code, then compile again, and fix the errors immediately.

Comment: The issue is that I understand "what" the errors mean, but I don't know how to fix them :/

Comment: `char lowerCase = ...`; defines a variable `lowerCase`, and initializes it. You can't declare a variable twice in the same scope. So the second lowerCase variable should be declared with another name: `char otherLowerCase = ...`. Or, if you want a single variable, and reuse it, you must not redeclare it, but only reassign it: `lowerCase = ...`.

Comment: Ok, I changed it to `lowerCase2` and it fixes the error. Not sure if it solves any problem that may arise when I eventually try running the program. I'm not sure on the other ones tho. Do they just need to be declared variables or are they full blown methods that need written or something?